# jQuery count total length of json data is not correct

Tags: jquery, json

I need to count length of `json` data. When I try to alert, it show me the total length of characters.

What I need is to count length of total `json`.

Means total is 9. imsak, fajr, sunrise, dhuhr, asr, sunset, maghrib, isha, midnight.

[image]

[image]

The above picture is the data.

What I've tried:

```
socket.on('buttonUpdate', function(data){   
    alert(data.length);
});
```

Comment: This should work `Object.keys(data).length`

Comment: Hi, it's still count 149

Comment: Working fine check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s4a82hfg/)

Comment: Now OK, cheers btw.